# StackOverflowError in String.toLowerCase

Tags: java, string, htmlunit, stack-overflow

It looks like a too long String causing folowing exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.String.toLowerCase(String.java:2496)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.NamedAttrNodeMapImpl.fixName(DomElement.java:489)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.NamedAttrNodeMapImpl.get(DomElement.java:602)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.getAttribute(DomElement.java:215)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleDeclaration.getStyleMap(CSSStyleDeclaration.java:634)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getStyleMap(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:243)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleDeclaration.getStyleAttribute(CSSStyleDeclaration.java:472)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getStyleAttribute(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:162)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleDeclaration.jsxGet_position(CSSStyleDeclaration.java:4008)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.jsxGet_position(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:1304)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getPositionWithInheritance(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:1883)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getTop(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:1737)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getTop(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:1769)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getTop(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:1769)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getTop(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:1769)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getTop(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:1769)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getTop(ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:1769)
```

I guess the loop in `ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration` causing this problem.

What is the physical limit of a String?
Can I limit the loop-detector for `ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration`?

Comment: Well it could naturally be caused by too deep html structures and the implementation using recursion instead of iteration.

Comment: String's length limit by array length,that is 2^31-1

Comment: Is there already a bug open about this? http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1233/

Comment: @emeraldjava BAM thats it. Please make this as an answer.

Comment: StackOverflow? You've come to the right place. . . .

Comment: @PeterRader Look at the source of `ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.java:1769` and the `ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration.getTop()` method, how does that work and why it calls itself with the same parameters.

Comment: can you paste your code out?

Comment: What java implementation are you using?  Looks like there may be different behaviors between the Oracle and OpenJDK versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there already a bug open about this? http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1233/

Answer (score 1):

The reason is a recursion-invoke existing in your code.  please check.

**At a deeper level of knowledge of JVM to explain this problem: the java virtual machine specification has ruled two situations of exception for java stack:**

1. Java stack is allowed to expand automaticly, it'll throw
   `OOM(OutOfMemory)` error when it cann't apply for enough memory.
2. Java stack is constituted with stack frame, and each java
       method push a frame, it'll throw the `StackOverflowError` when the
       stack depth of the current thread is larger than the jvm's allowed.

Maybe help you:)

Comment: `OutOfMemory` is and **Error**, not an Exception. You cant't catch `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: Well, you can catch it, it's just a really bad idea.